# Suspicious base64 code, no one knows from where. Is it harmless?

Tags: web-application, obfuscation

While doing some testing on my site I found this code at the bottom of several of our pages. It appears to be encoding for a scaleable vector file of Pinterest's logo, that's all fine and good, but I never put it there, and I don't think anyone else did. I'm concerned that it could be some sort of exploit. I'm not sure how to decipher this? I ran it through one level of decoding but it just made it look like a different kind of code.

Anyone know if this looks harmless, or is this something bad?

```
<p><span style="border-radius: 2px; text-indent: 20px; width: auto; padding: 0px 4px 0px 0px; text-align: center; font: bold 11px/20px 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,sans-serif; color: #ffffff; background: #bd081c url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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') no-repeat scroll 3px 50% / 14px 14px; position: absolute; opacity: 1; z-index: 8675309; display: none; cursor: pointer;">Save</span></p>
<p><span style="border-radius: 2px; text-indent: 20px; width: auto; padding: 0px 4px 0px 0px; text-align: center; font: bold 11px/20px 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,sans-serif; color: #ffffff; background: #bd081c url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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') no-repeat scroll 3px 50% / 14px 14px; position: absolute; opacity: 0.85; z-index: 8675309; display: none; cursor: pointer; top: 1311px; left: 146px;">Save</span></p>
<p><span style="border-radius: 2px; text-indent: 20px; width: auto; padding: 0px 4px 0px 0px; text-align: center; font: bold 11px/20px 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,sans-serif; color: #ffffff; background: #bd081c url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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') no-repeat scroll 3px 50% / 14px 14px; position: absolute; opacity: 1; z-index: 8675309; display: none; cursor: pointer;">Save</span></p>
<p><span style="border-radius: 2px; text-indent: 20px; width: auto; padding: 0px 4px 0px 0px; text-align: center; font: bold 11px/20px 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,sans-serif; color: #ffffff; background: #bd081c url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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') no-repeat scroll 3px 50% / 14px 14px; position: absolute; opacity: 0.85; z-index: 8675309; display: none; cursor: pointer; top: 2483px; left: 114px;">Save</span></p>
<p><span style="border-radius: 2px; text-indent: 20px; width: auto; padding: 0px 4px 0px 0px; text-align: center; font: bold 11px/20px 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,sans-serif; color: #ffffff; background: #bd081c url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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') no-repeat scroll 3px 50% / 14px 14px; position: absolute; opacity: 0.85; z-index: 8675309; display: none; cursor: pointer; top: 670px; left: 172px;">Save</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's what I got out of going through a decoder, doens't get me very far.

```
UEhOMlp5QjRiV3h1Y3owaWFIUjBjRG92TDNkM2R5NTNNeTV2Y21jdk1qQXdNQzl6ZG1jaUlHaGx
hV2RvZEQwaU16QndlQ0lnZDJsa2RHZzlJak13Y0hnaUlIWnBaWGRDYjNnOUlpMHhJQzB4SURNeE
lETXhJajQ4Wno0OGNHRjBhQ0JrUFNKTk1qa3VORFE1TERFMExqWTJNaUJETWprdU5EUTVMREl5T
GpjeU1pQXlNaTQ0Tmpnc01qa3VNalUySURFMExqYzFMREk1TGpJMU5pQkROaTQyTXpJc01qa3VN
alUySURBdU1EVXhMREl5TGpjeU1pQXdMakExTVN3eE5DNDJOaklnUXpBdU1EVXhMRFl1TmpBeEl
EWXVOak15TERBdU1EWTNJREUwTGpjMUxEQXVNRFkzSUVNeU1pNDROamdzTUM0d05qY2dNamt1Tk
RRNUxEWXVOakF4SURJNUxqUTBPU3d4TkM0Mk5qSWlJR1pwYkd3OUlpTm1abVlpSUhOMGNtOXJaV
```

```
DBpSTJabVppSWdjM1J5YjJ0bExYZHBaSFJvUFNJeElqNDhMM0JoZEdnK1BIQmhkR2dnWkQwaVRU
RTBMamN6TXl3eExqWTROaUJETnk0MU1UWXNNUzQyT0RZZ01TNDJOalVzTnk0ME9UVWdNUzQyTmp
Vc01UUXVOall5SUVNeExqWTJOU3d5TUM0eE5Ua2dOUzR4TURrc01qUXVPRFUwSURrdU9UY3NNal
l1TnpRMElFTTVMamcxTml3eU5TNDNNVGdnT1M0M05UTXNNalF1TVRReklERXdMakF4Tml3eU15N
HdNaklnUXpFd0xqSTFNeXd5TWk0d01TQXhNUzQxTkRnc01UWXVOVGN5SURFeExqVTBPQ3d4Tmk0
MU56SWdRekV4TGpVME9Dd3hOaTQxTnpJZ01URXVNVFUzTERFMUxqYzVOU0F4TVM0eE5UY3NNVFF
1TmpRMklFTXhNUzR4TlRjc01USXVPRFF5SURFeUxqSXhNU3d4TVM0ME9UVWdNVE11TlRJeUxERX
```

```
hMalE1TlNCRE1UUXVOak0zTERFeExqUTVOU0F4TlM0eE56VXNNVEl1TXpJMklERTFMakUzTlN3e
E15NHpNak1nUXpFMUxqRTNOU3d4TkM0ME16WWdNVFF1TkRZeUxERTJMakVnTVRRdU1Ea3pMREUz
TGpZME15QkRNVE11TnpnMUxERTRMamt6TlNBeE5DNDNORFVzTVRrdU9UZzRJREUyTGpBeU9Dd3h
PUzQ1T0RnZ1F6RTRMak0xTVN3eE9TNDVPRGdnTWpBdU1UTTJMREUzTGpVMU5pQXlNQzR4TXpZc0
1UUXVNRFEySUVNeU1DNHhNellzTVRBdU9UTTVJREUzTGpnNE9DdzRMamMyTnlBeE5DNDJOemdzT
0M0M05qY2dRekV3TGprMU9TdzRMamMyTnlBNExqYzNOeXd4TVM0MU16WWdPQzQzTnpjc01UUXVN
ems0SUVNNExqYzNOeXd4TlM0MU1UTWdPUzR5TVN3eE5pNDNNRGtnT1M0M05Ea3NNVGN1TXpVNUl
FTTVMamcxTml3eE55NDBPRGdnT1M0NE56SXNNVGN1TmlBNUxqZzBMREUzTGpjek1TQkRPUzQzTk
RFc01UZ3VNVFF4SURrdU5USXNNVGt1TURJeklEa3VORGMzTERFNUxqSXdNeUJET1M0ME1pd3hPU
```

```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```

Comment: Can't you simply check who added it when in your version control history? Or is the code only on the production server and not in version control?

Comment: As @CodesInChaos suggests it may just be somone else adding code that you need to track.[SVGs are unlikely to be a source for an attack](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11384/exploits-or-other-security-risks-with-svg-upload) though I suppose anything is possible...

Comment: Also, you may want to edit the post to include the decoded base64 in the question so that readers don't have to make the extra hop...

Comment: Tried to update, it.   We are not that sophisticated, we were outsourcing our backend stuff, I mainly just do front end design and marketing, little html, css, javascript, play with Jquery a bit but that's it, our IT guy knows networks, not code...  We do have some logs, but they are not permanent  and a bunch have been either erased... or there are huge gaps... :T

Comment: Casey this is not what I got running through the decoder. See @BlackMagic's answer below. Seems like a legit Pinterest SVG; what you are rightly worried about is how it got there.

Answer (score 2):

#### What is it?

What you have are harmless SVG vectors (that are base64 encoded) being parsed using [data uri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) in the image tag. This is a legitimate way of serving SVGs. Decoding these strings gives valid SVGs - which you can render online - https://jsfiddle.net/ykdss3b3/ (rendered as a "Save" button: https://jsfiddle.net/psL3p1hy/)

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="30px" width="30px" viewBox="-1 -1 31 31"><g><path d="M29.449,14.662 C29.449,22.722 22.868,29.256 14.75,29.256 C6.632,29.256 0.051,22.722 0.051,14.662 C0.051,6.601 6.632,0.067 14.75,0.067 C22.868,0.067 29.449,6.601 29.449,14.662" fill="#fff" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1"></path><path d="M14.733,1.686 C7.516,1.686 1.665,7.495 1.665,14.662 C1.665,20.159 5.109,24.854 9.97,26.744 C9.856,25.718 9.753,24.143 10.016,23.022 C10.253,22.01 11.548,16.572 11.548,16.572 C11.548,16.572 11.157,15.795 11.157,14.646 C11.157,12.842 12.211,11.495 13.522,11.495 C14.637,11.495 15.175,12.326 15.175,13.323 C15.175,14.436 14.462,16.1 14.093,17.643 C13.785,18.935 14.745,19.988 16.028,19.988 C18.351,19.988 20.136,17.556 20.136,14.046 C20.136,10.939 17.888,8.767 14.678,8.767 C10.959,8.767 8.777,11.536 8.777,14.398 C8.777,15.513 9.21,16.709 9.749,17.359 C9.856,17.488 9.872,17.6 9.84,17.731 C9.741,18.141 9.52,19.023 9.477,19.203 C9.42,19.44 9.288,19.491 9.04,19.376 C7.408,18.622 6.387,16.252 6.387,14.349 C6.387,10.256 9.383,6.497 15.022,6.497 C19.555,6.497 23.078,9.705 23.078,13.991 C23.078,18.463 20.239,22.062 16.297,22.062 C14.973,22.062 13.728,21.379 13.302,20.572 C13.302,20.572 12.647,23.05 12.488,23.657 C12.193,24.784 11.396,26.196 10.863,27.058 C12.086,27.434 13.386,27.637 14.733,27.637 C21.95,27.637 27.801,21.828 27.801,14.662 C27.801,7.495 21.95,1.686 14.733,1.686" fill="#bd081c"></path></g></svg>
```

#### How could it be there?

This depends on your set up;

- Multiple developers working on production
- Plugins installed it
- (if it's not in your source code) a browser add-on
- ...

#### What to do?

If you didn't put it there, or anybody else you know that has access to your server did, remove it, and clean your production box. <s>You *may* have been hacked - or</s> it could be completely harmless and be packaged with your website theme (ie: installing a theme via wordpress).

If you have no use for a Pintrest "save" button, remove it - it's probably part of the global move that renamed "Pin it" to "Save" (https://blog.pinterest.com/en/pinterest-save-button-goes-global) and you're not making the connection - so **absolutely harmless** and probably added via [add save button to your site](https://help.pinterest.com/en/articles/build-save-it-button-your-site).

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this a number of times on various sites, it's just a technique to provide those button images that scale with the button. It could be an attack I suppose, but what's more concerning is that you have no idea where code comes from on a site that you manage. You need to be looking into source control, at the very least for stability of your website so you can revert back to older versions if something goes wrong, but also as a log of who added what when.

[Bitbucket](http://www.bitbucket.org) is good option for hosting closed source projects if you have a small team of developers, using Git.

Answer (score -1):

As you can see in my edit, I actually decoded the base64 encoding for you. It seems to be harmless:
http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_path.asp

EDIT:
For reference

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="30px" width="30px" viewBox="-1 -1 31 31"><g><path d="M29.449,14.662 C29.449,22.722 22.868,29.256 14.75,29.256 C6.632,29.256 0.051,22.722 0.051,14.662 C0.051,6.601 6.632,0.067 14.75,0.067 C22.868,0.067 29.449,6.601 29.449,14.662" fill="#fff" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1"></path><path d="M14.733,1.686 C7.516,1.686 1.665,7.495 1.665,14.662 C1.665,20.159 5.109,24.854 9.97,26.744 C9.856,25.718 9.753,24.143 10.016,23.022 C10.253,22.01 11.548,16.572 11.548,16.572 C11.548,16.572 11.157,15.795 11.157,14.646 C11.157,12.842 12.211,11.495 13.522,11.495 C14.637,11.495 15.175,12.326 15.175,13.323 C15.175,14.436 14.462,16.1 14.093,17.643 C13.785,18.935 14.745,19.988 16.028,19.988 C18.351,19.988 20.136,17.556 20.136,14.046 C20.136,10.939 17.888,8.767 14.678,8.767 C10.959,8.767 8.777,11.536 8.777,14.398 C8.777,15.513 9.21,16.709 9.749,17.359 C9.856,17.488 9.872,17.6 9.84,17.731 C9.741,18.141 9.52,19.023 9.477,19.203 C9.42,19.44 9.288,19.491 9.04,19.376 C7.408,18.622 6.387,16.252 6.387,14.349 C6.387,10.256 9.383,6.497 15.022,6.497 C19.555,6.497 23.078,9.705 23.078,13.991 C23.078,18.463 20.239,22.062 16.297,22.062 C14.973,22.062 13.728,21.379 13.302,20.572 C13.302,20.572 12.647,23.05 12.488,23.657 C12.193,24.784 11.396,26.196 10.863,27.058 C12.086,27.434 13.386,27.637 14.733,27.637 C21.95,27.637 27.801,21.828 27.801,14.662 C27.801,7.495 21.95,1.686 14.733,1.686" fill="#bd081c"></path></g></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks all,   This is actually a Fashion Brand site, I'm in charge of the E-Commerce, division.  This code was over in the main Branding section where the CMS is modified by artists social media folks and anyone else with a  login although there is a log. on the CMS and I'm certain a much more Extensive log in the Database but I've never messed with that.